# git feature branch: rebase -i or merge --no-ff?

Tags: git

Many git workflows advocate doing a **git merge --no-ff** to bring a feature branch into the mainline.  I personally prefer to **git rebase -i** my feature branch into one clean commit, and then do a simple git merge of that.

Is there any downside to using rebase -i this way instead of merge --no-ff for feature branches?

Comment: `git merge --squash` will have roughly the same effect as how you're using `git rebase -i`, and requires less user interaction, meaning less chance to mess things up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`merge --no-ff`**, creates a new commit that have each HEAD (last commit) of the merged branches as parents, in your case: the last commit of "mainline" and the last commit of "feature" branch. This would make git remember that the "feature" branch history is part of the merge commit history.

History with `merge`, the merged commit `*` have both branches HEADs as parents:

```
mainline  ---------*
                  /
feature   -------/
```

With **`rebase -i`**, the new commit wouldn't include the HEAD of the "feature" branch in the list of parents of the rebased commit, so the repository would lose track the commit's previous history.

History with `rebase`, the rebased commit `*` have only one "mainline" HEAD as parent:

```
mainline  --------*

feature   --------
```

Remember that commits that have no references get garbage collected. If you use "rebase -i", it wouln't create a reference (as it is not included as a parent in the rebase commit), and if the "feature" branch ever gets delete, that history will be eventually pruned (completely deleted) by the garbage collector if there's no other reference around your repository.

Comment: so i guess the correct compromise would to rebase -i a messy feature branch into a few logical atomic commits and then merge --no-ff that?

Comment: This is just an opinion: I like to rebase and tiddy up only before *pushing* and making the commits public, leaving in the history the most important set of changes (squashing commits like "duh, fixing indentation or spaces" commits out but leaving most of the rest). Rebase'ing on a feature branch into the main branch, is not a bad idea (specially if you never shared the branch), just don't squash all the commits (leaving a single commit).

Comment: does `git merge --squash` have the same downside?

Comment: My group prefers to merge, because we like the "lane change" where the feature was brought in.